# How to reset the DB on each deployment on heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

So currently I'm working on a project on Heroku with Drupal and my issue is that I want to reset the database each time I deploy to master, yes I know it not ideal but its a development env because I'm working Drupal plugin and it would be nice if changes happened it could just reset to a state.

But when I try to connect using `psql` and some variables I just get `password authentication failed for user` even tho I know its the right password because I got it from Heroku itself.

Currently, I have tried using the console to try to make in connection soi could run a `DROP TABLE` command for me to afterword import an SQL file with the basic setup using pg_dump, and put it into a .sh script and run it with and `release:` in a procfile

Until now I have this as a release.sh file where I only tried in the console on heroku

```
PGHOST=HOST PGPORT=5432 \
PGDATABASE=DB \
PGUSER=USER PGPASSWORD=SOMEPASS \
psql
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP or Drupal? How **exactly** do you want to "reset" the DB - to which state should it be set?

Comment: @NicoHaase Like a total reset each time like it only need to drop all tables

Comment: Wouldn't that make your website completely useless?

Comment: @NicoHaase no because as i wrote i have an backup of the db in sql that should be importet with pg_dump

Answer (score 0):

Try below command to reset DB

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: You can create a file like seeder that will always execute before deployment and put this code on file